# How to call python script from java and return long text?

Tags: java, python

I need to call python script from Java application and return big text (json response). I successfully called script and i can return some text to Java application. But when i tried return full json response - my Java application freezes and nothing happend.
How i call python script:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "python", absolutePath, params
);
Process ps = pb.start();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream())
);

ps.waitFor();
int ec = ps.exitValue();
StringBuffer HTTPResponse = new StringBuffer();
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        logger.debug(String.format("DEBUG!!!: input = %s", inputLine));
        HTTPResponse.append(inputLine);
}
```

Comment: How long is your JSON , String can hold only  `2^31 - 1` characters .

Comment: My JSON has 20000-30000 characters

Comment: Could you post the snippet of Sample JSON which you are returning .

Comment: This is snippet of my JSON: { "date":"2015-07-24", "id":1, "model":"M1", "data":[ { "type":"type1", "cells":[ { "id":"1", "value":0.040064146030228266, "coordinates":[ [ -87.63091408173337, 41.795005325850376 ], [ -87.62907988011985, 41.79501538475784 ], [ -87.62909330288652, 41.79638796701671 ], [ -87.63092754363034, 41.79637790762748 ] ] }, { "id":"2", "value":0.03198091747638019, "coordinates":[ [ -87.618431048304, 41.83213480478867 ], [ -87.61659578273363, 41.83214467146507 ], [ -87.61660895627595, 41.83351724807935 ], [ -87.61844426105063, 41.83350738093046 ] ] } ] } ] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing a deadlock between parent and child processes.

This is because your java application does not read anything from the child process until it has terminated. Python will buffer it's output (up to 64k on my system), and once the buffer has filled it will block on the next write. Because it is blocked, it will not terminate. Meanwhile the java parent is also blocked waiting for the child to terminate, which will not happen naturally.

To fix this you need to restructure your Java code such that it, rather than waiting for the child to terminate before processing its output, reads from the child until the child terminates, something like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestProcess {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
       ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
           "python", absolutePath, params
       );
       Process ps = pb.start();

       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream())
       );

       String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(inputLine);
       }

       ps.waitFor();
       int ec = ps.exitValue();
       System.out.println("Child returned " + ec);
   }
}
```

And your Python script could be:

```
print 'a' * (1024*1024)
```

which would produce 1MiB of data.